# Calling a macro or a function at POST_BUILD step

Tags: cmake

CMake's `add_custom_command()` allows one to run a command (through the `COMMAND` option) before or after building the target (using `PRE_BUILD`, `PRE_LINK` and `POST_BUILD`). The command can be an executable or external "script", but not a CMake macro/function.

Is there a similar command like `add_custom_command()`, which instead allows passing of a CMake function/macro and schedule it before/after a target was built?
If not, what options are there, besides implementing the `COMMAND` as a re-run of CMake with a flag that enables the functionality inside the function/macro?

[EDIT] The function/macro will take as input the CMake target name and a target specific directory path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command *can* be a CMake macro or function. You just have to encapsulate it in a CMake file. CMake's [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) supports running further CMake code as a script, with the [`-P` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script). You can pass arguments to the function using the `-D` option as well. For this example, we will pass two arguments, `TARGET_NAME` and `TARGET_PATH`:

```
# Define the executable target.
add_executable(MyExecutable ${MY_SRCS})

add_custom_command(TARGET MyExecutable
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} 
        -DTARGET_NAME=MyExecutable
        -DTARGET_PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.cmake
    COMMENT "Running script..."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

The `my_script.cmake` file can include one or more pre-defined CMake functions, then call those functions, with something like this:

```
include(my_function.cmake)
# Call the function, passing the arguments we defined in add_custom_command.
my_function(${TARGET_NAME} ${TARGET_PATH})
```

For completeness, the CMake function `my_function` could look like this:

```
# My CMake function.
function(my_function target_name target_path)
    message("Target name: ${target_name}")
    message("Target directory: ${target_path}")
endfunction()
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! If anyone knows why there isn't such a built-in CMake command for this use-case already available, it would be nice to learn.

Comment: @MariusCH: "why there isn't such a built-in CMake command for this use-case already available" - See that answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835855/3440745.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: thank you for the link and for marking this as a duplicate.